# javascript - hidding table cells in search

Tags: javascript, html

In my website, I have a table with search box (radios). 
When webpage loads, the table results cells is hidden.
However after the search made, the results of the table does not hide again.

The search box when it returns empty, all cells in the table is show.

Thank you advance.
(Sorry my English)

```js
var accent_map = {
'ẚ':'a',
'Á':'a',
'á':'a',
'À':'a',
'à':'a',
'Ă':'a',
'ă':'a',
'Ắ':'a',
'ắ':'a',
'Ằ':'a',
'ằ':'a',
'Ẵ':'a',
'ẵ':'a',
'Ẳ':'a',
'ẳ':'a',
'Â':'a',
'â':'a',
'Ấ':'a',
'ấ':'a',
'Ầ':'a',
'ầ':'a',
'Ẫ':'a',
'ẫ':'a',
'Ẩ':'a',
'ẩ':'a',
'Ǎ':'a',
'ǎ':'a',
'Å':'a',
'å':'a',
'Ǻ':'a',
'ǻ':'a',
'Ä':'a',
'ä':'a',
'Ǟ':'a',
'ǟ':'a',
'Ã':'a',
'ã':'a',
'Ȧ':'a',
'ȧ':'a',
'Ǡ':'a',
'ǡ':'a',
'Ą':'a',
'ą':'a',
'Ā':'a',
'ā':'a',
'Ả':'a',
'ả':'a',
'Ȁ':'a',
'ȁ':'a',
'Ȃ':'a',
'ȃ':'a',
'Ạ':'a',
'ạ':'a',
'Ặ':'a',
'ặ':'a',
'Ậ':'a',
'ậ':'a',
'Ḁ':'a',
'ḁ':'a',
'Ⱥ':'a',
'ⱥ':'a',
'Ǽ':'a',
'ǽ':'a',
'Ǣ':'a',
'ǣ':'a',
'Ḃ':'b',
'ḃ':'b',
'Ḅ':'b',
'ḅ':'b',
'Ḇ':'b',
'ḇ':'b',
'Ƀ':'b',
'ƀ':'b',
'ᵬ':'b',
'Ɓ':'b',
'ɓ':'b',
'Ƃ':'b',
'ƃ':'b',
'Ć':'c',
'ć':'c',
'Ĉ':'c',
'ĉ':'c',
'Č':'c',
'č':'c',
'Ċ':'c',
'ċ':'c',
'Ç':'c',
'ç':'c',
'Ḉ':'c',
'ḉ':'c',
'Ȼ':'c',
'ȼ':'c',
'Ƈ':'c',
'ƈ':'c',
'ɕ':'c',
'Ď':'d',
'ď':'d',
'Ḋ':'d',
'ḋ':'d',
'Ḑ':'d',
'ḑ':'d',
'Ḍ':'d',
'ḍ':'d',
'Ḓ':'d',
'ḓ':'d',
'Ḏ':'d',
'ḏ':'d',
'Đ':'d',
'đ':'d',
'ᵭ':'d',
'Ɖ':'d',
'ɖ':'d',
'Ɗ':'d',
'ɗ':'d',
'Ƌ':'d',
'ƌ':'d',
'ȡ':'d',
'ð':'d',
'É':'e',
'Ə':'e',
'Ǝ':'e',
'ǝ':'e',
'é':'e',
'È':'e',
'è':'e',
'Ĕ':'e',
'ĕ':'e',
'Ê':'e',
'ê':'e',
'Ế':'e',
'ế':'e',
'Ề':'e',
'ề':'e',
'Ễ':'e',
'ễ':'e',
'Ể':'e',
'ể':'e',
'Ě':'e',
'ě':'e',
'Ë':'e',
'ë':'e',
'Ẽ':'e',
'ẽ':'e',
'Ė':'e',
'ė':'e',
'Ȩ':'e',
'ȩ':'e',
'Ḝ':'e',
'ḝ':'e',
'Ę':'e',
'ę':'e',
'Ē':'e',
'ē':'e',
'Ḗ':'e',
'ḗ':'e',
'Ḕ':'e',
'ḕ':'e',
'Ẻ':'e',
'ẻ':'e',
'Ȅ':'e',
'ȅ':'e',
'Ȇ':'e',
'ȇ':'e',
'Ẹ':'e',
'ẹ':'e',
'Ệ':'e',
'ệ':'e',
'Ḙ':'e',
'ḙ':'e',
'Ḛ':'e',
'ḛ':'e',
'Ɇ':'e',
'ɇ':'e',
'ɚ':'e',
'ɝ':'e',
'Ḟ':'f',
'ḟ':'f',
'ᵮ':'f',
'Ƒ':'f',
'ƒ':'f',
'Ǵ':'g',
'ǵ':'g',
'Ğ':'g',
'ğ':'g',
'Ĝ':'g',
'ĝ':'g',
'Ǧ':'g',
'ǧ':'g',
'Ġ':'g',
'ġ':'g',
'Ģ':'g',
'ģ':'g',
'Ḡ':'g',
'ḡ':'g',
'Ǥ':'g',
'ǥ':'g',
'Ɠ':'g',
'ɠ':'g',
'Ĥ':'h',
'ĥ':'h',
'Ȟ':'h',
'ȟ':'h',
'Ḧ':'h',
'ḧ':'h',
'Ḣ':'h',
'ḣ':'h',
'Ḩ':'h',
'ḩ':'h',
'Ḥ':'h',
'ḥ':'h',
'Ḫ':'h',
'ḫ':'h',
'H':'h',
'̱':'h',
'ẖ':'h',
'Ħ':'h',
'ħ':'h',
'Ⱨ':'h',
'ⱨ':'h',
'Í':'i',
'í':'i',
'Ì':'i',
'ì':'i',
'Ĭ':'i',
'ĭ':'i',
'Î':'i',
'î':'i',
'Ǐ':'i',
'ǐ':'i',
'Ï':'i',
'ï':'i',
'Ḯ':'i',
'ḯ':'i',
'Ĩ':'i',
'ĩ':'i',
'İ':'i',
'i':'i',
'Į':'i',
'į':'i',
'Ī':'i',
'ī':'i',
'Ỉ':'i',
'ỉ':'i',
'Ȉ':'i',
'ȉ':'i',
'Ȋ':'i',
'ȋ':'i',
'Ị':'i',
'ị':'i',
'Ḭ':'i',
'ḭ':'i',
'I':'i',
'ı':'i',
'Ɨ':'i',
'ɨ':'i',
'Ĵ':'j',
'ĵ':'j',
'J':'j',
'̌':'j',
'ǰ':'j',
'ȷ':'j',
'Ɉ':'j',
'ɉ':'j',
'ʝ':'j',
'ɟ':'j',
'ʄ':'j',
'Ḱ':'k',
'ḱ':'k',
'Ǩ':'k',
'ǩ':'k',
'Ķ':'k',
'ķ':'k',
'Ḳ':'k',
'ḳ':'k',
'Ḵ':'k',
'ḵ':'k',
'Ƙ':'k',
'ƙ':'k',
'Ⱪ':'k',
'ⱪ':'k',
'Ĺ':'a',
'ĺ':'l',
'Ľ':'l',
'ľ':'l',
'Ļ':'l',
'ļ':'l',
'Ḷ':'l',
'ḷ':'l',
'Ḹ':'l',
'ḹ':'l',
'Ḽ':'l',
'ḽ':'l',
'Ḻ':'l',
'ḻ':'l',
'Ł':'l',
'ł':'l',
'Ł':'l',
'̣':'l',
'ł':'l',
'̣':'l',
'Ŀ':'l',
'ŀ':'l',
'Ƚ':'l',
'ƚ':'l',
'Ⱡ':'l',
'ⱡ':'l',
'Ɫ':'l',
'ɫ':'l',
'ɬ':'l',
'ɭ':'l',
'ȴ':'l',
'Ḿ':'m',
'ḿ':'m',
'Ṁ':'m',
'ṁ':'m',
'Ṃ':'m',
'ṃ':'m',
'ɱ':'m',
'Ń':'n',
'ń':'n',
'Ǹ':'n',
'ǹ':'n',
'Ň':'n',
'ň':'n',
'Ñ':'n',
'ñ':'n',
'Ṅ':'n',
'ṅ':'n',
'Ņ':'n',
'ņ':'n',
'Ṇ':'n',
'ṇ':'n',
'Ṋ':'n',
'ṋ':'n',
'Ṉ':'n',
'ṉ':'n',
'Ɲ':'n',
'ɲ':'n',
'Ƞ':'n',
'ƞ':'n',
'ɳ':'n',
'ȵ':'n',
'N':'n',
'̈':'n',
'n':'n',
'̈':'n',
'Ó':'o',
'ó':'o',
'Ò':'o',
'ò':'o',
'Ŏ':'o',
'ŏ':'o',
'Ô':'o',
'ô':'o',
'Ố':'o',
'ố':'o',
'Ồ':'o',
'ồ':'o',
'Ỗ':'o',
'ỗ':'o',
'Ổ':'o',
'ổ':'o',
'Ǒ':'o',
'ǒ':'o',
'Ö':'o',
'ö':'o',
'Ȫ':'o',
'ȫ':'o',
'Ő':'o',
'ő':'o',
'Õ':'o',
'õ':'o',
'Ṍ':'o',
'ṍ':'o',
'Ṏ':'o',
'ṏ':'o',
'Ȭ':'o',
'ȭ':'o',
'Ȯ':'o',
'ȯ':'o',
'Ȱ':'o',
'ȱ':'o',
'Ø':'o',
'ø':'o',
'Ǿ':'o',
'ǿ':'o',
'Ǫ':'o',
'ǫ':'o',
'Ǭ':'o',
'ǭ':'o',
'Ō':'o',
'ō':'o',
'Ṓ':'o',
'ṓ':'o',
'Ṑ':'o',
'ṑ':'o',
'Ỏ':'o',
'ỏ':'o',
'Ȍ':'o',
'ȍ':'o',
'Ȏ':'o',
'ȏ':'o',
'Ơ':'o',
'ơ':'o',
'Ớ':'o',
'ớ':'o',
'Ờ':'o',
'ờ':'o',
'Ỡ':'o',
'ỡ':'o',
'Ở':'o',
'ở':'o',
'Ợ':'o',
'ợ':'o',
'Ọ':'o',
'ọ':'o',
'Ộ':'o',
'ộ':'o',
'Ɵ':'o',
'ɵ':'o',
'Ṕ':'p',
'ṕ':'p',
'Ṗ':'p',
'ṗ':'p',
'Ᵽ':'p',
'Ƥ':'p',
'ƥ':'p',
'P':'p',
'̃':'p',
'p':'p',
'̃':'p',
'ʠ':'q',
'Ɋ':'q',
'ɋ':'q',
'Ŕ':'r',
'ŕ':'r',
'Ř':'r',
'ř':'r',
'Ṙ':'r',
'ṙ':'r',
'Ŗ':'r',
'ŗ':'r',
'Ȑ':'r',
'ȑ':'r',
'Ȓ':'r',
'ȓ':'r',
'Ṛ':'r',
'ṛ':'r',
'Ṝ':'r',
'ṝ':'r',
'Ṟ':'r',
'ṟ':'r',
'Ɍ':'r',
'ɍ':'r',
'ᵲ':'r',
'ɼ':'r',
'Ɽ':'r',
'ɽ':'r',
'ɾ':'r',
'ᵳ':'r',
'ß':'s',
'Ś':'s',
'ś':'s',
'Ṥ':'s',
'ṥ':'s',
'Ŝ':'s',
'ŝ':'s',
'Š':'s',
'š':'s',
'Ṧ':'s',
'ṧ':'s',
'Ṡ':'s',
'ṡ':'s',
'ẛ':'s',
'Ş':'s',
'ş':'s',
'Ṣ':'s',
'ṣ':'s',
'Ṩ':'s',
'ṩ':'s',
'Ș':'s',
'ș':'s',
'ʂ':'s',
'S':'s',
'̩':'s',
's':'s',
'̩':'s',
'Þ':'t',
'þ':'t',
'Ť':'t',
'ť':'t',
'T':'t',
'̈':'t',
'ẗ':'t',
'Ṫ':'t',
'ṫ':'t',
'Ţ':'t',
'ţ':'t',
'Ṭ':'t',
'ṭ':'t',
'Ț':'t',
'ț':'t',
'Ṱ':'t',
'ṱ':'t',
'Ṯ':'t',
'ṯ':'t',
'Ŧ':'t',
'ŧ':'t',
'Ⱦ':'t',
'ⱦ':'t',
'ᵵ':'t',
'ƫ':'t',
'Ƭ':'t',
'ƭ':'t',
'Ʈ':'t',
'ʈ':'t',
'ȶ':'t',
'Ú':'u',
'ú':'u',
'Ù':'u',
'ù':'u',
'Ŭ':'u',
'ŭ':'u',
'Û':'u',
'û':'u',
'Ǔ':'u',
'ǔ':'u',
'Ů':'u',
'ů':'u',
'Ü':'u',
'ü':'u',
'Ǘ':'u',
'ǘ':'u',
'Ǜ':'u',
'ǜ':'u',
'Ǚ':'u',
'ǚ':'u',
'Ǖ':'u',
'ǖ':'u',
'Ű':'u',
'ű':'u',
'Ũ':'u',
'ũ':'u',
'Ṹ':'u',
'ṹ':'u',
'Ų':'u',
'ų':'u',
'Ū':'u',
'ū':'u',
'Ṻ':'u',
'ṻ':'u',
'Ủ':'u',
'ủ':'u',
'Ȕ':'u',
'ȕ':'u',
'Ȗ':'u',
'ȗ':'u',
'Ư':'u',
'ư':'u',
'Ứ':'u',
'ứ':'u',
'Ừ':'u',
'ừ':'u',
'Ữ':'u',
'ữ':'u',
'Ử':'u',
'ử':'u',
'Ự':'u',
'ự':'u',
'Ụ':'u',
'ụ':'u',
'Ṳ':'u',
'ṳ':'u',
'Ṷ':'u',
'ṷ':'u',
'Ṵ':'u',
'ṵ':'u',
'Ʉ':'u',
'ʉ':'u',
'Ṽ':'v',
'ṽ':'v',
'Ṿ':'v',
'ṿ':'v',
'Ʋ':'v',
'ʋ':'v',
'Ẃ':'w',
'ẃ':'w',
'Ẁ':'w',
'ẁ':'w',
'Ŵ':'w',
'ŵ':'w',
'W':'w',
'̊':'w',
'ẘ':'w',
'Ẅ':'w',
'ẅ':'w',
'Ẇ':'w',
'ẇ':'w',
'Ẉ':'w',
'ẉ':'w',
'Ẍ':'x',
'ẍ':'x',
'Ẋ':'x',
'ẋ':'x',
'Ý':'y',
'ý':'y',
'Ỳ':'y',
'ỳ':'y',
'Ŷ':'y',
'ŷ':'y',
'Y':'y',
'̊':'y',
'ẙ':'y',
'Ÿ':'y',
'ÿ':'y',
'Ỹ':'y',
'ỹ':'y',
'Ẏ':'y',
'ẏ':'y',
'Ȳ':'y',
'ȳ':'y',
'Ỷ':'y',
'ỷ':'y',
'Ỵ':'y',
'ỵ':'y',
'ʏ':'y',
'Ɏ':'y',
'ɏ':'y',
'Ƴ':'y',
'ƴ':'y',
'Ź':'z',
'ź':'z',
'Ẑ':'z',
'ẑ':'z',
'Ž':'z',
'ž':'z',
'Ż':'z',
'ż':'z',
'Ẓ':'z',
'ẓ':'z',
'Ẕ':'z',
'ẕ':'z',
'Ƶ':'z',
'ƶ':'z',
'Ȥ':'z',
'ȥ':'z',
'ʐ':'z',
'ʑ':'z',
'Ⱬ':'z',
'ⱬ':'z',
'Ǯ':'z',
'ǯ':'z',
'ƺ':'z',

// Roman fullwidth ascii equivalents: 0xff00 to 0xff5e
'２':'2',
'６':'6',
'Ｂ':'B',
'Ｆ':'F',
'Ｊ':'J',
'Ｎ':'N',
'Ｒ':'R',
'Ｖ':'V',
'Ｚ':'Z',
'ｂ':'b',
'ｆ':'f',
'ｊ':'j',
'ｎ':'n',
'ｒ':'r',
'ｖ':'v',
'ｚ':'z',
'１':'1',
'５':'5',
'９':'9',
'Ａ':'A',
'Ｅ':'E',
'Ｉ':'I',
'Ｍ':'M',
'Ｑ':'Q',
'Ｕ':'U',
'Ｙ':'Y',
'ａ':'a',
'ｅ':'e',
'ｉ':'i',
'ｍ':'m',
'ｑ':'q',
'ｕ':'u',
'ｙ':'y',
'０':'0',
'４':'4',
'８':'8',
'Ｄ':'D',
'Ｈ':'H',
'Ｌ':'L',
'Ｐ':'P',
'Ｔ':'T',
'Ｘ':'X',
'ｄ':'d',
'ｈ':'h',
'ｌ':'l',
'ｐ':'p',
'ｔ':'t',
'ｘ':'x',
'３':'3',
'７':'7',
'Ｃ':'C',
'Ｇ':'G',
'Ｋ':'K',
'Ｏ':'O',
'Ｓ':'S',
'Ｗ':'W',
'ｃ':'c',
'ｇ':'g',
'ｋ':'k',
'ｏ':'o',
'ｓ':'s',
'ｗ':'w'};

var accentMap = {
    'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u'
};

function accent_fold (s) {
 if (!s) { return ''; }
    var ret = '';
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  ret += accent_map[s.charAt(i)] || s.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
};


// accent_folded_hilite("Fulanilo López", 'lo')
//   --> "Fulani<b>lo</b> <b>Ló</b>pez"
//
function accent_folded_hilite(str, q) {
  var str_folded = accent_fold(str).toLowerCase().replace(/[<>]+/g, '');
  var q_folded = accent_fold(q).toLowerCase().replace(/[<>]+/g, '');

  // create an intermediary string with hilite hints
  // example: fulani<lo> <lo>pez
  var re = new RegExp(q_folded, 'g');
  var hilite_hints = str_folded.replace(re, '<'+q_folded+'>');

  // index pointer for the original string
  var spos = 0;
  // accumulator for our final string
  var highlighted = '';

  // walk down the original string and the hilite hint
  // string in parallel. when you encounter a < or > hint,
  // append the opening / closing tag in our final string.
  // if the current char is not a hint, append the corresponding
  // char from the *original* string to our final string and
  // advance the original string's pointer.
  for (var i=0; i<hilite_hints.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charAt(spos);
    var h = hilite_hints.charAt(i);
    if (h === '<') {
       highlighted += '<b>';
    } else if (h === '>') {
       highlighted += '</b>';
    } else {
      spos += 1;
      highlighted += c;
    }
  }
  return highlighted;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase;" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Type Radio Name" title="Type in a name">

<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Radio Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">List (Position)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RÁDIO</td>
    <td>PORTUGAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RADIO</td>
    <td>PORTUGAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RADIO 10</td>
    <td>PORTUGAL</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
  
  function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = accent_fold(input.value).toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      if (td) {
        if (accent_fold(td.innerHTML).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)');
   
   if (input.value.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  </script>
```

Thank you advance.
(Sorry my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to `input` outside of `myFunction` so the if check is always false if you put it in the function like this.

```js
var accent_map = {
'ẚ':'a',
'Á':'a',
'á':'a',
'À':'a',
'à':'a',
'Ă':'a',
'ă':'a',
'Ắ':'a',
'ắ':'a',
'Ằ':'a',
'ằ':'a',
'Ẵ':'a',
'ẵ':'a',
'Ẳ':'a',
'ẳ':'a',
'Â':'a',
'â':'a',
'Ấ':'a',
'ấ':'a',
'Ầ':'a',
'ầ':'a',
'Ẫ':'a',
'ẫ':'a',
'Ẩ':'a',
'ẩ':'a',
'Ǎ':'a',
'ǎ':'a',
'Å':'a',
'å':'a',
'Ǻ':'a',
'ǻ':'a',
'Ä':'a',
'ä':'a',
'Ǟ':'a',
'ǟ':'a',
'Ã':'a',
'ã':'a',
'Ȧ':'a',
'ȧ':'a',
'Ǡ':'a',
'ǡ':'a',
'Ą':'a',
'ą':'a',
'Ā':'a',
'ā':'a',
'Ả':'a',
'ả':'a',
'Ȁ':'a',
'ȁ':'a',
'Ȃ':'a',
'ȃ':'a',
'Ạ':'a',
'ạ':'a',
'Ặ':'a',
'ặ':'a',
'Ậ':'a',
'ậ':'a',
'Ḁ':'a',
'ḁ':'a',
'Ⱥ':'a',
'ⱥ':'a',
'Ǽ':'a',
'ǽ':'a',
'Ǣ':'a',
'ǣ':'a',
'Ḃ':'b',
'ḃ':'b',
'Ḅ':'b',
'ḅ':'b',
'Ḇ':'b',
'ḇ':'b',
'Ƀ':'b',
'ƀ':'b',
'ᵬ':'b',
'Ɓ':'b',
'ɓ':'b',
'Ƃ':'b',
'ƃ':'b',
'Ć':'c',
'ć':'c',
'Ĉ':'c',
'ĉ':'c',
'Č':'c',
'č':'c',
'Ċ':'c',
'ċ':'c',
'Ç':'c',
'ç':'c',
'Ḉ':'c',
'ḉ':'c',
'Ȼ':'c',
'ȼ':'c',
'Ƈ':'c',
'ƈ':'c',
'ɕ':'c',
'Ď':'d',
'ď':'d',
'Ḋ':'d',
'ḋ':'d',
'Ḑ':'d',
'ḑ':'d',
'Ḍ':'d',
'ḍ':'d',
'Ḓ':'d',
'ḓ':'d',
'Ḏ':'d',
'ḏ':'d',
'Đ':'d',
'đ':'d',
'ᵭ':'d',
'Ɖ':'d',
'ɖ':'d',
'Ɗ':'d',
'ɗ':'d',
'Ƌ':'d',
'ƌ':'d',
'ȡ':'d',
'ð':'d',
'É':'e',
'Ə':'e',
'Ǝ':'e',
'ǝ':'e',
'é':'e',
'È':'e',
'è':'e',
'Ĕ':'e',
'ĕ':'e',
'Ê':'e',
'ê':'e',
'Ế':'e',
'ế':'e',
'Ề':'e',
'ề':'e',
'Ễ':'e',
'ễ':'e',
'Ể':'e',
'ể':'e',
'Ě':'e',
'ě':'e',
'Ë':'e',
'ë':'e',
'Ẽ':'e',
'ẽ':'e',
'Ė':'e',
'ė':'e',
'Ȩ':'e',
'ȩ':'e',
'Ḝ':'e',
'ḝ':'e',
'Ę':'e',
'ę':'e',
'Ē':'e',
'ē':'e',
'Ḗ':'e',
'ḗ':'e',
'Ḕ':'e',
'ḕ':'e',
'Ẻ':'e',
'ẻ':'e',
'Ȅ':'e',
'ȅ':'e',
'Ȇ':'e',
'ȇ':'e',
'Ẹ':'e',
'ẹ':'e',
'Ệ':'e',
'ệ':'e',
'Ḙ':'e',
'ḙ':'e',
'Ḛ':'e',
'ḛ':'e',
'Ɇ':'e',
'ɇ':'e',
'ɚ':'e',
'ɝ':'e',
'Ḟ':'f',
'ḟ':'f',
'ᵮ':'f',
'Ƒ':'f',
'ƒ':'f',
'Ǵ':'g',
'ǵ':'g',
'Ğ':'g',
'ğ':'g',
'Ĝ':'g',
'ĝ':'g',
'Ǧ':'g',
'ǧ':'g',
'Ġ':'g',
'ġ':'g',
'Ģ':'g',
'ģ':'g',
'Ḡ':'g',
'ḡ':'g',
'Ǥ':'g',
'ǥ':'g',
'Ɠ':'g',
'ɠ':'g',
'Ĥ':'h',
'ĥ':'h',
'Ȟ':'h',
'ȟ':'h',
'Ḧ':'h',
'ḧ':'h',
'Ḣ':'h',
'ḣ':'h',
'Ḩ':'h',
'ḩ':'h',
'Ḥ':'h',
'ḥ':'h',
'Ḫ':'h',
'ḫ':'h',
'H':'h',
'̱':'h',
'ẖ':'h',
'Ħ':'h',
'ħ':'h',
'Ⱨ':'h',
'ⱨ':'h',
'Í':'i',
'í':'i',
'Ì':'i',
'ì':'i',
'Ĭ':'i',
'ĭ':'i',
'Î':'i',
'î':'i',
'Ǐ':'i',
'ǐ':'i',
'Ï':'i',
'ï':'i',
'Ḯ':'i',
'ḯ':'i',
'Ĩ':'i',
'ĩ':'i',
'İ':'i',
'i':'i',
'Į':'i',
'į':'i',
'Ī':'i',
'ī':'i',
'Ỉ':'i',
'ỉ':'i',
'Ȉ':'i',
'ȉ':'i',
'Ȋ':'i',
'ȋ':'i',
'Ị':'i',
'ị':'i',
'Ḭ':'i',
'ḭ':'i',
'I':'i',
'ı':'i',
'Ɨ':'i',
'ɨ':'i',
'Ĵ':'j',
'ĵ':'j',
'J':'j',
'̌':'j',
'ǰ':'j',
'ȷ':'j',
'Ɉ':'j',
'ɉ':'j',
'ʝ':'j',
'ɟ':'j',
'ʄ':'j',
'Ḱ':'k',
'ḱ':'k',
'Ǩ':'k',
'ǩ':'k',
'Ķ':'k',
'ķ':'k',
'Ḳ':'k',
'ḳ':'k',
'Ḵ':'k',
'ḵ':'k',
'Ƙ':'k',
'ƙ':'k',
'Ⱪ':'k',
'ⱪ':'k',
'Ĺ':'a',
'ĺ':'l',
'Ľ':'l',
'ľ':'l',
'Ļ':'l',
'ļ':'l',
'Ḷ':'l',
'ḷ':'l',
'Ḹ':'l',
'ḹ':'l',
'Ḽ':'l',
'ḽ':'l',
'Ḻ':'l',
'ḻ':'l',
'Ł':'l',
'ł':'l',
'Ł':'l',
'̣':'l',
'ł':'l',
'̣':'l',
'Ŀ':'l',
'ŀ':'l',
'Ƚ':'l',
'ƚ':'l',
'Ⱡ':'l',
'ⱡ':'l',
'Ɫ':'l',
'ɫ':'l',
'ɬ':'l',
'ɭ':'l',
'ȴ':'l',
'Ḿ':'m',
'ḿ':'m',
'Ṁ':'m',
'ṁ':'m',
'Ṃ':'m',
'ṃ':'m',
'ɱ':'m',
'Ń':'n',
'ń':'n',
'Ǹ':'n',
'ǹ':'n',
'Ň':'n',
'ň':'n',
'Ñ':'n',
'ñ':'n',
'Ṅ':'n',
'ṅ':'n',
'Ņ':'n',
'ņ':'n',
'Ṇ':'n',
'ṇ':'n',
'Ṋ':'n',
'ṋ':'n',
'Ṉ':'n',
'ṉ':'n',
'Ɲ':'n',
'ɲ':'n',
'Ƞ':'n',
'ƞ':'n',
'ɳ':'n',
'ȵ':'n',
'N':'n',
'̈':'n',
'n':'n',
'̈':'n',
'Ó':'o',
'ó':'o',
'Ò':'o',
'ò':'o',
'Ŏ':'o',
'ŏ':'o',
'Ô':'o',
'ô':'o',
'Ố':'o',
'ố':'o',
'Ồ':'o',
'ồ':'o',
'Ỗ':'o',
'ỗ':'o',
'Ổ':'o',
'ổ':'o',
'Ǒ':'o',
'ǒ':'o',
'Ö':'o',
'ö':'o',
'Ȫ':'o',
'ȫ':'o',
'Ő':'o',
'ő':'o',
'Õ':'o',
'õ':'o',
'Ṍ':'o',
'ṍ':'o',
'Ṏ':'o',
'ṏ':'o',
'Ȭ':'o',
'ȭ':'o',
'Ȯ':'o',
'ȯ':'o',
'Ȱ':'o',
'ȱ':'o',
'Ø':'o',
'ø':'o',
'Ǿ':'o',
'ǿ':'o',
'Ǫ':'o',
'ǫ':'o',
'Ǭ':'o',
'ǭ':'o',
'Ō':'o',
'ō':'o',
'Ṓ':'o',
'ṓ':'o',
'Ṑ':'o',
'ṑ':'o',
'Ỏ':'o',
'ỏ':'o',
'Ȍ':'o',
'ȍ':'o',
'Ȏ':'o',
'ȏ':'o',
'Ơ':'o',
'ơ':'o',
'Ớ':'o',
'ớ':'o',
'Ờ':'o',
'ờ':'o',
'Ỡ':'o',
'ỡ':'o',
'Ở':'o',
'ở':'o',
'Ợ':'o',
'ợ':'o',
'Ọ':'o',
'ọ':'o',
'Ộ':'o',
'ộ':'o',
'Ɵ':'o',
'ɵ':'o',
'Ṕ':'p',
'ṕ':'p',
'Ṗ':'p',
'ṗ':'p',
'Ᵽ':'p',
'Ƥ':'p',
'ƥ':'p',
'P':'p',
'̃':'p',
'p':'p',
'̃':'p',
'ʠ':'q',
'Ɋ':'q',
'ɋ':'q',
'Ŕ':'r',
'ŕ':'r',
'Ř':'r',
'ř':'r',
'Ṙ':'r',
'ṙ':'r',
'Ŗ':'r',
'ŗ':'r',
'Ȑ':'r',
'ȑ':'r',
'Ȓ':'r',
'ȓ':'r',
'Ṛ':'r',
'ṛ':'r',
'Ṝ':'r',
'ṝ':'r',
'Ṟ':'r',
'ṟ':'r',
'Ɍ':'r',
'ɍ':'r',
'ᵲ':'r',
'ɼ':'r',
'Ɽ':'r',
'ɽ':'r',
'ɾ':'r',
'ᵳ':'r',
'ß':'s',
'Ś':'s',
'ś':'s',
'Ṥ':'s',
'ṥ':'s',
'Ŝ':'s',
'ŝ':'s',
'Š':'s',
'š':'s',
'Ṧ':'s',
'ṧ':'s',
'Ṡ':'s',
'ṡ':'s',
'ẛ':'s',
'Ş':'s',
'ş':'s',
'Ṣ':'s',
'ṣ':'s',
'Ṩ':'s',
'ṩ':'s',
'Ș':'s',
'ș':'s',
'ʂ':'s',
'S':'s',
'̩':'s',
's':'s',
'̩':'s',
'Þ':'t',
'þ':'t',
'Ť':'t',
'ť':'t',
'T':'t',
'̈':'t',
'ẗ':'t',
'Ṫ':'t',
'ṫ':'t',
'Ţ':'t',
'ţ':'t',
'Ṭ':'t',
'ṭ':'t',
'Ț':'t',
'ț':'t',
'Ṱ':'t',
'ṱ':'t',
'Ṯ':'t',
'ṯ':'t',
'Ŧ':'t',
'ŧ':'t',
'Ⱦ':'t',
'ⱦ':'t',
'ᵵ':'t',
'ƫ':'t',
'Ƭ':'t',
'ƭ':'t',
'Ʈ':'t',
'ʈ':'t',
'ȶ':'t',
'Ú':'u',
'ú':'u',
'Ù':'u',
'ù':'u',
'Ŭ':'u',
'ŭ':'u',
'Û':'u',
'û':'u',
'Ǔ':'u',
'ǔ':'u',
'Ů':'u',
'ů':'u',
'Ü':'u',
'ü':'u',
'Ǘ':'u',
'ǘ':'u',
'Ǜ':'u',
'ǜ':'u',
'Ǚ':'u',
'ǚ':'u',
'Ǖ':'u',
'ǖ':'u',
'Ű':'u',
'ű':'u',
'Ũ':'u',
'ũ':'u',
'Ṹ':'u',
'ṹ':'u',
'Ų':'u',
'ų':'u',
'Ū':'u',
'ū':'u',
'Ṻ':'u',
'ṻ':'u',
'Ủ':'u',
'ủ':'u',
'Ȕ':'u',
'ȕ':'u',
'Ȗ':'u',
'ȗ':'u',
'Ư':'u',
'ư':'u',
'Ứ':'u',
'ứ':'u',
'Ừ':'u',
'ừ':'u',
'Ữ':'u',
'ữ':'u',
'Ử':'u',
'ử':'u',
'Ự':'u',
'ự':'u',
'Ụ':'u',
'ụ':'u',
'Ṳ':'u',
'ṳ':'u',
'Ṷ':'u',
'ṷ':'u',
'Ṵ':'u',
'ṵ':'u',
'Ʉ':'u',
'ʉ':'u',
'Ṽ':'v',
'ṽ':'v',
'Ṿ':'v',
'ṿ':'v',
'Ʋ':'v',
'ʋ':'v',
'Ẃ':'w',
'ẃ':'w',
'Ẁ':'w',
'ẁ':'w',
'Ŵ':'w',
'ŵ':'w',
'W':'w',
'̊':'w',
'ẘ':'w',
'Ẅ':'w',
'ẅ':'w',
'Ẇ':'w',
'ẇ':'w',
'Ẉ':'w',
'ẉ':'w',
'Ẍ':'x',
'ẍ':'x',
'Ẋ':'x',
'ẋ':'x',
'Ý':'y',
'ý':'y',
'Ỳ':'y',
'ỳ':'y',
'Ŷ':'y',
'ŷ':'y',
'Y':'y',
'̊':'y',
'ẙ':'y',
'Ÿ':'y',
'ÿ':'y',
'Ỹ':'y',
'ỹ':'y',
'Ẏ':'y',
'ẏ':'y',
'Ȳ':'y',
'ȳ':'y',
'Ỷ':'y',
'ỷ':'y',
'Ỵ':'y',
'ỵ':'y',
'ʏ':'y',
'Ɏ':'y',
'ɏ':'y',
'Ƴ':'y',
'ƴ':'y',
'Ź':'z',
'ź':'z',
'Ẑ':'z',
'ẑ':'z',
'Ž':'z',
'ž':'z',
'Ż':'z',
'ż':'z',
'Ẓ':'z',
'ẓ':'z',
'Ẕ':'z',
'ẕ':'z',
'Ƶ':'z',
'ƶ':'z',
'Ȥ':'z',
'ȥ':'z',
'ʐ':'z',
'ʑ':'z',
'Ⱬ':'z',
'ⱬ':'z',
'Ǯ':'z',
'ǯ':'z',
'ƺ':'z',

// Roman fullwidth ascii equivalents: 0xff00 to 0xff5e
'２':'2',
'６':'6',
'Ｂ':'B',
'Ｆ':'F',
'Ｊ':'J',
'Ｎ':'N',
'Ｒ':'R',
'Ｖ':'V',
'Ｚ':'Z',
'ｂ':'b',
'ｆ':'f',
'ｊ':'j',
'ｎ':'n',
'ｒ':'r',
'ｖ':'v',
'ｚ':'z',
'１':'1',
'５':'5',
'９':'9',
'Ａ':'A',
'Ｅ':'E',
'Ｉ':'I',
'Ｍ':'M',
'Ｑ':'Q',
'Ｕ':'U',
'Ｙ':'Y',
'ａ':'a',
'ｅ':'e',
'ｉ':'i',
'ｍ':'m',
'ｑ':'q',
'ｕ':'u',
'ｙ':'y',
'０':'0',
'４':'4',
'８':'8',
'Ｄ':'D',
'Ｈ':'H',
'Ｌ':'L',
'Ｐ':'P',
'Ｔ':'T',
'Ｘ':'X',
'ｄ':'d',
'ｈ':'h',
'ｌ':'l',
'ｐ':'p',
'ｔ':'t',
'ｘ':'x',
'３':'3',
'７':'7',
'Ｃ':'C',
'Ｇ':'G',
'Ｋ':'K',
'Ｏ':'O',
'Ｓ':'S',
'Ｗ':'W',
'ｃ':'c',
'ｇ':'g',
'ｋ':'k',
'ｏ':'o',
'ｓ':'s',
'ｗ':'w'};

var accentMap = {
    'á':'a', 'é':'e', 'í':'i','ó':'o','ú':'u'
};

function accent_fold (s) {
 if (!s) { return ''; }
    var ret = '';
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  ret += accent_map[s.charAt(i)] || s.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
};


// accent_folded_hilite("Fulanilo López", 'lo')
//   --> "Fulani<b>lo</b> <b>Ló</b>pez"
//
function accent_folded_hilite(str, q) {
  var str_folded = accent_fold(str).toLowerCase().replace(/[<>]+/g, '');
  var q_folded = accent_fold(q).toLowerCase().replace(/[<>]+/g, '');

  // create an intermediary string with hilite hints
  // example: fulani<lo> <lo>pez
  var re = new RegExp(q_folded, 'g');
  var hilite_hints = str_folded.replace(re, '<'+q_folded+'>');

  // index pointer for the original string
  var spos = 0;
  // accumulator for our final string
  var highlighted = '';

  // walk down the original string and the hilite hint
  // string in parallel. when you encounter a < or > hint,
  // append the opening / closing tag in our final string.
  // if the current char is not a hint, append the corresponding
  // char from the *original* string to our final string and
  // advance the original string's pointer.
  for (var i=0; i<hilite_hints.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charAt(spos);
    var h = hilite_hints.charAt(i);
    if (h === '<') {
       highlighted += '<b>';
    } else if (h === '>') {
       highlighted += '</b>';
    } else {
      spos += 1;
      highlighted += c;
    }
  }
  return highlighted;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase;" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Type Radio Name" title="Type in a name">

<div id="table-wrapper">
  <div id="table-scroll">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Radio Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">List (Position)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RÁDIO</td>
    <td>PORTUGAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RADIO</td>
    <td>PORTUGAL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RADIO 10</td>
    <td>PORTUGAL</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
  
  function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = accent_fold(input.value).toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
      if (td) {
        if (accent_fold(td.innerHTML).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.header)');
   
    if (input.value.length == 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
  }

  

  </script>
```

Now it should work.